# Migrating (creating or updating) Indexes and Type Mappgins on Elasticsearch

Tags: firebase, elasticsearch, angular5, elasticsearch-curator

I've started a new Serverless Angular 5 application hosted on Firebase.

In this app, a number of Elasticsearch's indices and types must be maintained.

I have been looking for a solution that would allow me to **automate** the creation/update of indexes and/or type mappings automagically during/after the app deploy (something *similar* to what Rails/Laravel migrations do).

The closest thing that I've found so far, was the [curator](https://github.com/elastic/curator) tool.

Yet, after running few tests, I could not managed to automate:

- The creation of indexes and/or type mappings *only if they don't exist*.
- The update indexes and/or type mappings *only when necessary*.

Before trying to [handle this issue myself](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/124317/elastic-search-index-mapping-creation), I would like to know if there is a proper technique to approach this matter?

Answer (score 0):

Curator is about index management and cleanup of existing indices, and less about creation.  Creation is more the realm of [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.1/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) (which would be a server app).  If you want to be serverless, I think you will probably have to get familiar with elasticsearch's REST API.

The steps you have to do are not too difficult.  If more or less depends on your rules of when to create.  Logstash, by default, uses daily rotation by looking at a timestamp, deciding the index name, and (thanks to untergeek) relies on elastic's dynamic index creation if that index does not exist it.  I'll leave the link if you want to [create](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html) them manually as it can be as simple as:

```
PUT index-name
```

You can define a lot more settings on creation, but depending on your needs you can work more simply with [templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indices-templates.html).  This lets you define how your mappings can work at a general level.  You can define a template per index, or wildcarded group of indices.  You can define each mapping explicitly, or rely on [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html).  With a template defined, new indices created that match the name pattern will receive those settings and type mappings.

If your expected mappings are not very large, dynamic mapping can be very nice.  If they are large, just note that at each new index, the dynamic operation is a high priority task and can bog things down if you are currently attempting to index a large volume of data.

Logstash has some nice sample [mapping templates](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/tree/master/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch) (though it looks like elastic changed `template` to be `index_patterns` in 6.x and they have not updated the templates).

You'll probably have some sanity checks to do about when to name your index, but their docs guide you through most of the REST calls you'll need.  I know this is not much of an answer, so I hope someone already did this in a JS library, but  hope this helps in case no one has.

Comment: Technically speaking, Logstash does not actually create indices.  It takes advantage of Elasticsearch's dynamic index creation feature in that if you send a document to Elasticsearch and the index it is intended to go in does not exist, Elasticsearch will automatically create the index (and apply any templates which may be associated with it).  All Logstash does is send a constant stream of documents to the bulk API, with the name of the index each document needs to go to as part of each request. It let's Elasticsearch handle index creation.